# Complexity of sorting a string array

Tags: sorting, time-complexity

Assume we have an string array str = ["foo", "bar", "zebras", "topper"] which I need to to sort to get  ["bar", "foo", "zebra", "top"], the sorting complexity will be O(nlogn) where n is the length of the array. But we also do string compare, which should be O(m) where m is the length of longest strings (such as zebras and topper). So final complexity should be O(m * nlogn). Please correct me if I am wrong.

This question differs from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453526/complexity-of-binary-search-on-a-string/33453556#33453556) because, here I am comparing all strings with all strings, rather than a fixed string with just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result you would get if you performed sort using only normal string comparison.

You can get better performance (but I don't now of any implementations of this) by knowing your inputs are strings. For example, if you sort the strings by each character in turn, which gives O(n*m*|alphabet|).

Comment: So assuming I only used normal String comparison,  am I correct. ?

Comment: Yes, you are. Usually the complexity of sort is expressed in terms of number of comparisons (and swaps), so if your comparisons are O(m) (as they are), the sort is O(m*n*log(n))